# Is it possible to have just one Amazon policy that replaces multiples values based on a tag key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I would like to know if I can have just one policy attached to many IAM roles, where the policy replaces the buckets tags based on the IAM role key and value. For example, I have two IAM roles with the next key:value:

IAM role 1:

> buckets:["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-dev", "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-prod"]
>
> bucketsPath:["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-dev/root/*",
> "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-prod/user/*"]

IAM role 2:

> buckets:["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-pre", "arn:aws:s3:::otherbucket-dev"]
>
> bucketsPath:["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-pre/root/*",
> "arn:aws:s3:::otherbucket-dev/user/*"]

My first question is, can I have a list in the value?
[image]
I imagine the policy something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "aws:TagsKeys/buckets"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "aws:TagsKeys/bucketsPaths",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/jobposition": [
                        "dataengineer",
                        "admin"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to create IAM roles based on Active Directory groups that define specifics buckets and paths permissions in S3. I would like to create IAM roles based on tags using a few policies. The previous explanation It was my way to explain my problem, I already know that is not a possible solution for that reason I want alternatives.

Comment: something like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/tagging-iot-iam.html

Comment: Yes something similar, probably with a regular expressions. For example, I have a key=buckets and value=bucket1-bucket2-bucket-...-bucketN, so I can split by "-" but I don't know how to create a kind of list to assign as "Resource": ["aws:PrincipalTag/bucket1", "aws:PrincipalTag/bucket2", ..., "aws:PrincipalTag/bucketN"]